# How to invoke method of a controller from another one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirecttoaction

I want to call a method of controller A from controller B and get its return value.

How can I do that?

**ControllerA:**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ParentModel> GetParentModel(string contractNumberPar)
{
    try
    {
        // (...) - some code
        var viewModel = new ParentModel
        {
            // (...) - some code
        };
    
        return viewModel;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**ControllerB:**

```
ParentModel viewModel = RedirectToAction(
                       "ControllerA",
                       "GetParentModel",
                       new
                       {
                           contractNumberPar = contractNumber
                       });
```

Error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirecttoaction to (....).ParentModel

Comment: Probably the best way is to have a BaseController from which your front-end controllers derive and move the common code in that BaseController

Comment: But how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better create a common service,so that you can reuse it in both A and B controllers,here is a demo:

service:

```
public class MyService
{
    public async Task<ParentModel> GetParentModel(string contractNumberPar)
    {
        try
        {
            // (...) - some code
            var viewModel = new ParentModel
            {
                // (...) - some code
            };

            return viewModel;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

register the service(before .net6 in Startup.cs):

```
services.AddScoped<MyAccountService>();
```

register the service(.net6,.net7 in Program.cs):

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyService>();
```

BController:

```
public class BController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyService MyService;

        public BController(MyService myService)
        {
            MyService = myService;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
        { 
            string contractNumber="1";
            ParentModel viewModel = await MyService.GetParentModel(contractNumber);
            return Ok(viewModel);
        }
        
    }
```